# The typeof operator is not operating as expected

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, undefined, typeof

I am attempting to check if a particular javascript object exists.

```
var success = function(data) {

     var x= 0;
     var numOfCards = data.length;

     for (x=0;x<data.length - 1;x++)
        {
          if (typeof data[x].labels[0].name !== 'undefined')
            {
              alert("Object Exists");
            }
        }
     }
```

However, Chrome receives the following error:

> (index):21 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Surely, my use of typeof to check the status of the object should not, in itself, result in an error? On first iteration, the alert box displays as expected because:

> data[0].labels[0].name = "I am a value"

However,

> data[0].labels[1].name

causes the error as the "labels" array is empty.

Comment: `typeof` simply returns the "type" of a value. You can certainly get an error when evaluating the expression that generates the value. Example: `typeof foo()`. If `foo` is not a function, this will throw an error.

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely working as expected.

> Surely, my use of typeof to check the status of the object should not, in itself, result in an error?

Sure, if `name` were undefined. In this case, `data[0].labels[0]` is already undefined!

You would have to nest `if` statements with a `typeof` for each level if you wanted to allow all levels to be `undefined`, before examining the nested objects therein.

Comment: How I wish Javascript had inline existence operators much like Coffeescript and Ruby has so that you aren't encumbered by the overhead of manually writing those nested checks.  e.g. `data[0]?.labels[0]?.name`

Answer (score 0):

before checking if typeof data[x].labels[0].name !== 'undefined', make sure that typeof data[x].labels[0] !== 'undefined

```
if (typeof data[x].labels[0] !== 'undefined')
{
    alert("Object Exists");
}
```